# Rails route for .xml file: Template is Missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, routes, sitemap

I'm trying to upload an .xml sitemap to my Rails app called `sitemap.xml`. When I define a route as such:

```
  get "sitemap", to: 'xml#sitemap'
```

I get the following error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template xml/sitemap, application/sitemap with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/user/website/app/views"
```

How can I define a proper Rails route for an .xml file?

Comment: not too much info to go on... i assume you have a controller action named sitemap inside `xmls_controller.rb`?  Do you have a folder named `xmls` in your views with the file, 'sitemap.html.erb'?

Comment: is it okay if you put your `sitemap.xml` to your `public` folder instead?

Comment: @nayiaw How would I define a url for something in my public folder?

Comment: @RickyMason I have no such controller action. All I have is a file called 'sitemap.xml' in my xml folder.

Comment: if you want to load static `sitemap.xml` you can put the `sitemap.xml` in your public folder then load the sitemap directly `<domain.com>/sitemap.xml` without any routing. However use a sitemap generator like [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) is recommended as content changes over time.

Comment: @nayiaw Putting the file in my public folder worked great! If you write that as an answer I can select it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load static `sitemap.xml` you can put the `sitemap.xml` in your public folder, then load the sitemap directly `<domain.com>/sitemap.xml` without any routing. However use a sitemap generator like [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) is recommended as content changes over time.